# Plot data with one column as the major tick and another as the minor

Tags: r, plot, time-series, data-visualization, axis-labels

I have aggregated some time series data at an hourly level for a week. To do so, I split the datetimes and generated two columns in a data frame - one indicating the hour and the other the day of the week.

I want to plot the entire data with the x axis major tick labels as the day of the week and minor ticks as the hours of the day in ascending order.

This is the code I am using, but it only plots it with respect to one column.  Should I be converting my two columns into one timestamp again before plotting?

```
dotplot( Vol ~ Day.Hour, data=merged, type="l",xlab="Time(Day.Hour)",ylab="Number of People Departure/Arrival")
```

My data looks similar to this:

```
Day.Hour     Hour      Day      Vol
   Sun.0        0      Sun     2557
   Fri.3        3      Fri     4050
```

Comment: `dotplot` is a defunct R function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#reproducible example
merged = read.table(header=T, sep=" ", text="
Day.Hour Hour Day Vol
Sun.0 0 Sun 2557
Sun.3 3 Sun 1234
Sun.6 6 Sun 2045
Sun.9 9 Sun 4050")
```

Add a column in the df with sequence values. I am supposing your time series has a **fixed and continuous time interval**.

```
merged = data.frame(merged,Seq=seq(1,nrow(merged))) #add column Seq
merged #visualize the new data

  Day.Hour Hour Day  Vol Seq
1    Sun.0    0 Sun 2557   1
2    Sun.3    3 Sun 1234   2
3    Sun.6    6 Sun 2045   3
4    Sun.9    9 Sun 4050   4
```

Plot the line chart with two "x" axis referring to hours and weekdays, respectively.

```
plot(merged$Seq, merged$Vol, 
     type="l",
     xlab="Time(Day.Hour)",ylab="Number of People Departure/Arrival",
     col.axis="white", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
axis(side=1, at=merged$Seq, labels = merged$Hour,tick=F)
axis(side=1, at=merged$Seq, labels = merged$Day, padj=1.5)
axis(side=2, at=round(seq(min(merged$Vol),
                          max(merged$Vol),
                          by=((max(merged$Vol)-min(merged$Vol))/3)),0)) #plot only four values in y axis starting on minimum and ending on maximum
```

[image]